# awk or other shell to convert delimited list into a table

Tags: shell, awk

So what I have is a huge csv akin to this:

```
Pool1,Shard1,Event1,10
Pool1,Shard1,Event2,20
Pool1,Shard2,Event1,30
Pool1,Shard2,Event4,40
Pool2,Shard1,Event3,50
```

etc

Which is not ealisy readable. Eith there being only 4 types of events I'm useing spreadsheets to convert this into the following:

```
Pool1,Shard1,10,20,,
Pool1,Shard2,30,,,40
Pool2,Shard1,,,50,
```

Only events are limited to 4, pools and shards can be indefinite really. But the events may be missing from the lines - not all pools/shards have all 4 events every day.

So I tried doing this within an awk in the shell script that gathers the csv in the first place, but I'm failing spectacuraly, no working code can even be shown since it's producing zero results.

Basically I tried sorting the CSV reading the first two fields of a row, comparing to previous row and if matching comparing the third field to a set array of event strings then storing the fouth field in a variable respective to the event, and one the first two fileds are not matching - finally print the whole line including variables.

Sorry for the one-liner, testing and experimenting directly in the command line. It's embarassing, it does nothing.

```
awk -F, '{if (a==$1&&b==$2) {if ($3=="Event1") {r=$4} ; if ($3=="Event2") {d=$4} ; if ($3=="Event3") {t=$4} ; if ($3=="Event4") {p=$4}} else {printf $a","$b","$r","$d","$p","$t"\n"; a=$1 ; b=$2 ; if ($3=="Event1") {r=$4} ; if ($3=="Event2") {d=$4} ; if ($3=="Event3") {t=$4} ; if ($3=="Event4") {p=$4} ; a=$1; b=$2}} END {printf "\n"}'
```

Comment: awk isn't a shell. A shell is a tool to create/destroy files and processes and sequence calls to tools to perform tasks. Awk is the tool that the guys who invented shell also invented for shell to call to manipulate text.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use an assoc array: `awk -F, -f parse.awk input.csv` with `parse.awk` being:

```
{
    sub(/Event/, "", $3);
    res[$1","$2][$3]=$4;
}

END {
    for (name in res) {
        printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", name, res[name][1], res[name][2], res[name][3], res[name][4])
    }
}
```

Order could be confused by awk, but my test output is:

```
Pool2,Shard1,,,50,
Pool1,Shard1,10,20,,
Pool1,Shard2,30,,,40
```

PS: Please use an editor to write awk source code. Your one-liner is really hard to read. Since I used a different approach, I did not even try do get it "right"... ;)

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ key = $1 OFS $2 }
key != prev {
    if ( NR>1 ) {
        print prev, f["Event1"], f["Event2"], f["Event3"], f["Event4"]
        delete f
    }
    prev = key
}
{ f[$3] = $4 }
END { print key, f["Event1"], f["Event2"], f["Event3"], f["Event4"] }
```

```
$ sort file | awk -f tst.awk
Pool1,Shard1,10,20,,
Pool1,Shard2,30,,,40
Pool2,Shard1,,,50,
```